# What is the significance of these obelisks?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

Every map I've played so far seems to have a feature in common: pairs of obelisks that serve as a chokepoint between areas.

[image]

The colors vary, but they're always there.  Is this just a favorite feature of the map generator, or do they have some additional significance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The obelisks that appear on the coasts indicate where you can land a ship.

The obelisks on land appear where one towns territory ends and the next towns territory begins.  The color of the obelisk corresponds to the color of the player that currently controls the town (with gray representing a neutral town).

Comment: Didn't know the ship thing. But since water is neutral territory it actually also falls in the category of territory edge.